# What program reads and executes /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf and related scripts?

Tags: audio, alsa

I can't find any kind of daemon application for modern ALSA. I wonder, what process or kernel thread reads `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` and other configuration files under `/usr/share/alsa`, when it reads them and what kernel structures it updates (I suppose, it updates configuration spaces of kernel modules-drivers of audio hardware)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These configuration files are used by the ALSA library (`libasound.so.2`), which is used by every program that uses ALSA.

Comment: Thanks, CL. May be you know, how ALSA applications decide, to what devices their input/output streams should be redirected? E.g. my default sound device is PulseAudio and applications such as Gnash transfer sound through it. But I can mute PulseAudio and unmute another ALSA device, corresponding to hardware output device, e.g. `HDA ATI SB` via `alsamixer` or `amixer`. Does `alsamixer` or `amixer` inform `libasound` about those changes? Also, how Gnash decides, whether it should transfer its output stream to unmuted device or not? Does this depend on the application?